# SSRS 2008 help. What is a data scope

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am working with ssrs 2008. I am using this expression `=Sum(IiF(Fields!RegisterID.Value=6000,1,0)` and `if(Fields!PointID.Value=500,1,0))/Sum(Iif(Fields!PointID.Value=500,1,0))` when I go to run it I get this error message The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox1’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one data set. What do i need to do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using multiple datasets in your report.
All you need to do is specify your scope in the expression.

Your Expression without a scope:

```
=Sum(IiF(Fields!RegisterID.Value=6000,1,0) and Iif(Fields!PointID.Value=500,1,0))/Sum(Iif(Fields!PointID.Value=500,1,0))
```

Your Expression Fixed with scope included:

```
=Sum(IiF(Fields!RegisterID.Value, "PutYourDatasetNameHere" =6000,1,0) and Iif(Fields!PointID.Value, "PutYourDatasetNameHere" =500,1,0))/Sum(Iif(Fields!PointID.Value, "PutYourDatasetNameHere" =500,1,0))
```

Please Note: 
If you have multiple tables, make sure you specify the correct scope.

Example:

=SUM(Fields!RegisterID.Value, "Dataset1")
=SUM(Fields!RegisterID.Value, "Dataset2")